# Fetch an array of photos from wordpress gallery

Tags: wordpress, gallery

Do you know if there is any plugin or tutorial that describes how to do it? I would be very grateful for any help cause I am not very good at PHP.

I would like to add photos on Wordpress page and paste it as standard gallery into the post content, then I would like to aviod displaying the gallery but what I am interested about is to fetch an array of photos in that gallery and then iterate through it.

What is it for? I am developing a website http://www.rasterbyte.com/ and I want to use these images as background slideshow (Press left/right key to change picture). Currently images have fixed path, I want them to be custom for each page.

Thank you very much for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Maciek Simm,

As i understood your question, you have images in post and you want to display at background.

You can set home page category have 5 post with featured image.

fatch specific post image

```
<?php $args = array(
    'width' => null,
    'height' => null,
    'css' => '',
    'parent_id' => '',
    'post_id' => '',
    'filename' => '',
    'return_html' => true       
); ?>
```

Or For [more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Also check [How to: Get the first image from the post and display it](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-get-the-first-image-from-the-post-and-display-it)

```
function catch_that_image() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```